# Questions about stable rank of inductive limit of $C^\ast$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be an inductive limit of $\{A_n\}$ which are stable rank one. In Huaxin Lin's book *An introduction to the classification of amenable $C^\ast$-algebra*. The author assume that $\{A_n\}$ and $A$ are unital and $1_{A_n}=1_A$ in the proof of $A$ is stable rank one. (See Proposition 3.2.1 (1) on page 120)

There are two questions:

1. Why it can be assumed that  $\{A_n\}$ and $A$ are unital and $1_{A_n}=1_A$?
2. Why is an invertible element $z$ in $A_n$ invertible in $A$?

Can anyone give me a hint to answer these questions?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Look at Definition 3.1.1; 
2. When passing to a larger algebra with the same unit the spectrum cannot possibly grow